# How to initialise a generic declared Kotlin MutableStateFlow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

Im investigating Kotlin `MutableStateFlow`/`StateFlow` and would like to declare my `MutableStateFlow` in a Generic Base Class as follows:-

```
class MyBaseClass<S> {

private val internalState = MutableStateFlow<S>(//WHAT GOES HERE????//)

    val state: StateFlow<S>
        get() = internalState

}
```

The issue I am stuck with is that MutableStateFlow has a mandatory initial value.

I cannot see how to provide a generic initial value of Type "`S`"

Is it possible to use this approach of employing a generic base class instance variable?

Comment: I found this question useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477903/instantiating-a-generic-type-in-kotlin

Comment: Anyways, I think you can wrap S with something, that you can instantiate via known constructor/provider. Maybe some wrapper class?

Comment: @Steyrix thanks for the suggestion, I had already see that question/answer, however I do not like the idea of using .class constructors etc

Comment: Can't you just add a parameter to the constructor of `MyBaseClass<S>` indicating the default value, and then just pass that to `MutableStateFlow<S>()`?

Answer (score 3):

Building up on Harshith Shetty answer all I did differently was to initialize the `internalState` as lazy so I can avoid the `accessing non-final property in constructor` warning

```
abstract class MyBaseClass<S> {

    abstract val initialState: S

    private val internalState: MutableStateFlow<S> by lazy { MutableStateFlow(initialState) }

    val state: StateFlow<S>
        get() = internalState

}
```

Btw there is no way to inizialize MutableStateFlow without initial value. If you absolutely do not want an initial value use `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` instead.

e.g.

`val internalState: ConflatedBroadcastChannel<S> = ConflatedBroadcastChannel()`

Answer (score 2):

You can take the default initial state value from derived class like,

```
abstract class MyBaseClass<S> {

    abstract val initialState: S

    private val internalState = MutableStateFlow<S>(initialState)

    val state: StateFlow<S>
        get() = internalState

}
```